# How two .java files can use one xml layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I have two GetMyLocation.java,RoomBooking.java and JSONParser.java and main.xml which provides the user provision to book. Exactly what i want is to help me know how the two .java files can launch at once as one activity shown by main.xml. I tried to combine the two java files into one but i failed since am still new to android development. Here is my code

RoomBooking.java

```
public class RoomBooking extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputRoomType;
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputContact;

    EditText inputDetails;

    // url to submit new booking
    private static String url_submit = "http://192.168.1.177/lacrema/roomdetails.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Edit Text
        inputRoomType=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.roomcategory);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact);

        inputDetails = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.roomdetails);

        // Create button
        Button btnSubmitDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmitdetails);

        // button click event
        btnSubmitDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // submit new crime in background thread
                new SubmitDetails().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to submit new booking
     * */
    class SubmitDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RoomBooking.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Submitting 
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String roomtype=inputRoomType.getText().toString();
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String contact = inputContact.getText().toString();

            String details = inputDetails.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RoomType", roomtype));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Contact", contact));

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Details", details));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that submit url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_submit,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully submitted 
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetCurrentLocation.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to submit 
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
 }
```

GetCurrentLocation.java

```
public class GetCurrentLocation extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private LocationManager locationMangaer=null;
    private LocationListener locationListener=null; 

    private Button btnGetLocation = null;
    private EditText editLocation = null;   
    private ProgressBar pb =null;

    private static final String TAG = "Debug";
    private Boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        //if you want to lock screen for always Portrait mode  
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        editLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);  

        btnGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

        locationMangaer = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flag = displayGpsStatus();
        if (flag) {

            Log.v(TAG, "onClick");      

            editLocation.setText("Please!! move your device to see the changes in coordinates."+"\nWait..");

            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

            locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,
                    locationListener);

            } else {
            alertbox("Gps Status!!", "Your GPS is: OFF");
        }

    }

    /*----------Method to Check GPS is enable or disable ------------- */
    private Boolean displayGpsStatus() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
        boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(
                contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (gpsStatus) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*----------Method to create an AlertBox ------------- */
    protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your Device's GPS is Disable")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("** Gps Status **")
                .setPositiveButton("Gps On",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // finish the current activity
                                // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(myIntent);
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // cancel the dialog box
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    /*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

                editLocation.setText("");
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude()
                                + " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude();  
                Log.v(TAG, longitude);
                String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude();
                Log.v(TAG, latitude);

                /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
                String cityName=null;                 
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());                  
                List<Address>  addresses;  
                try {  
                 addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);  
                 if (addresses.size() > 0)  
                  System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());  
                 cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();  
                } catch (IOException e) {                 
                 e.printStackTrace();  
                } 

                String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude +"\n\nMy Currrent City is: "+cityName;
                editLocation.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1.  Enter room Category "
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/roomcategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2.  Your Full Names (OPTIONAL)"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3.  Your Phone Contact (REQUIRED)"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4.  Please Enter Your Physical Address"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4.  Please Give The Details"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/roomdetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />




    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Current Location and City Name"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:id="@+id/editTextLocation"
        android:editable="false">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>

        android:id="@+id/layButtonH"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.15">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get Location"
            android:id="@+id/btnLocation"></Button>

        android:id="@+id/layloadingH"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsubmitdetails"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#600"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="Cambria"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT DETAILS"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you might want to look into using fragments. its kind of exactly what I think you want to do.

Comment: So you mean i should use fragments. i create different xml layouts for the java files and then put them on a fragment. will i need to change anything in the codes?

Comment: if you want both java files to be in the same "activity" then you should use fragments. Fragments essentially are code that run in their own lifecycle but is bounded by the parent activity lifecycle. You can find good examples of this when writing code for a tablet vs. a phone.   The tablet will have more screen real estate to accompany another "activity" so you can run them side by side. You will need to change your code for sure.

Comment: is there anyway you can help me combine the two java files into one.

Comment: I dont' understand what you mean, just merge the two files together and have it implement the click listener.

Comment: Someone help me please i have failed. am still new to android